# Matlab user cropped image and then processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to make a program where I have an image and I display it to the user, and the user then crops out the unimportant part, while matlab waits for him to finish. Then the rest of the program is run where the image processing is done on the part of the image that is left.

I found the 'waitfor' function but I am not sure how it is to used in this case. Also will the corresponding matrix be updated with the values of the cropped image?

Comment: See the Matlab function `imcrop` from the Image Processing Toolbox

Comment: Salut Aniss, j'ai vu que toi aussi tu étais sur stack overflow :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need `imcrop`

It's a matlab tool to crop images. You draw the rectangles, and then you can move it. You double-click to finish.

[image]